# Gradle dependencies for different api levels

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin

unfortunately I have to support Android 2.3, but I want to use a third party ui widget that has min-sdk 14 (Android 4.0).

Is there a way to include the dependency with min-sdk 14?

In code I would check `Build.SDK_INT` to determine whether to use the ui widget with min SDK 14 or a fallback UI widget.

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible... If you have a dependency it is inside you compilation. inside your apk. You can choose if you want to use this third party lib with if(SDK_INT) but the lib will be compiled and in your app.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, since you have to include a dependency it will always be compiled into your project.

You could break your project out into separate projects. If you created something like a `BaseApp` and a `IceCreamSandwichApp` you could set different `minSdkVersions` for each along with a different set of dependencies.

So you would have to modules in your app:

```
your-app/BaseApp
```

and

```
your-app/IceCreamSandwichApp
```

And your gradle files would look something like this:

**your-app/settings.gradle**

```
include ':BaseApp', ':GingerbreadApp'
```

**your-app/BaseApp/build.gradle**

```
android {
    buildToolsVersion '22.0.1'

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 9
        compileSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 21
    }

...

    dependencies {
        compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    }

}
```

**your-app/IceCreamSandwichApp/build.gradle**

```
android {
    buildToolsVersion '22.0.1'

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 14
        compileSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 21
    }

...

    dependencies {
        compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
        compile project(":BaseApp")
        compile 'the.third.party:lib:here:1.0.0'
    }

}
```