# Conditionally declare dependency based on Android API level - Gradle

Tags: android, gradle, sharedpreferences, androidx, android-library

I've written a library which is already used by a few people, it revolves around `EncryptedSharedPreferences` which is only available starting at API 23. However, there is a runtime check that falls back to using the normal `SharedPreferences` when running on a API 23 or lower device. I would like to be able to support API 16+ instead.

At the moment, Gradle will not build unless you explicitly override the `minSdkVersion` for this in your app's manifest.

Is there another way around this? I've read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26787246/gradle-dependencies-for-different-api-levels) which suggests creating two different projects with their own `minSdkVersion` but I'm not sure if it applies in this case.

Answer (score 0):

In build.gradle (Module: MyProject.app). In this case I'm ingnoring spectratech implementation when minSdkVersion > 24.

```
println('cdvCompileSdkVersion=' + android.defaultConfig.minSdkVersion.mApiLevel)
if( android.defaultConfig.minSdkVersion.mApiLevel > 24 ){
    implementation(name: 'com.spectratech.printercontrollers-0.00.10-apollotappos-release', ext: 'aar')
}
```